# Online - Create choice field using workflow and HTTP call

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to create a field in a document library using a SharePoint 2013 workflow and HTTP call.

Based on what I found here: https://gist.github.com/MartinBodocky/8056791, I'm trying to reproduce the call on a SharePoint Workflow.

I've created a Workflow variable with this dictionary:
(name) / (type) / (value)

- __metadata / type Dictionary / Variable: metadata
- Title / type String / Activity
- FieldTypeKing / type Integer / 6
- Required / type Boolean / False
- Choices / type Dictionary / Variable: dictionaryActivities

In detail, the `metadata` variable:

- type / type String / SP.FieldChoice

Then I've created the `dictionaryActivities` variable like this:

- results / type String / 'Activity 1', 'Activity 2', 'Activity 3'

Then I created the HTTP call (POST) to this URL:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/revisioni/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('[%Current Item:Sport Name%]')/fields
```

The call failed trying the Workflow. I think the problem is in the `dictionaryActivities` variable and its type.
This is what web service returned as ResponseCode:

```
BadRequest
```

Any suggestion? What is the correct variable type to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tmp string as {"results": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]}

Then, set Choices as dictionary and returnd from tmp string.

[image]

Comment: Great! It works! Do you know if it is possible to add this field to default view using the same REST call?

Comment: That's different endpoint: /_api/web/lists(guid'list id')/views(guid'view id')/ViewFields/AddField